# Non-alphanumeric character folder name auto-completion problems

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I have been working with Windows 7's command line and have some folders that begin with non-alphanumeric characters. When I try to use tab completion to complete the folder name, the initial character is not included inside of the quotation marks.
Example: `C:\Users\username\!example` is the folder I want to get into, but when I type:

```
cd !
```

and press `<Tab>` to autocomplete, it will complete to

```
cd !"!example"
```

instead of the expected

```
cd "!example"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this besides changing the folder names?

**EDIT:** I realize I could just tab through the entire list after entering `cd`, but I'm looking for a way to speed up the process. I have been spending a significant amount of time navigating these folders.

**UPDATE:** This also happens if there is a space in the directory. For example: "c:\Program Files". In order to continue using tab to complete, first the second quote has to be deleted.

C:\Program

press Tab

"C:\Program Files" is what appears. To navigate to a subdirectory, first the quote after Program Files has to be deleted before the next directory can be spelled out.

Comment: Still looking for help on this...

Comment: In `cmd`, the `!` is not recognised as the first character of file/dir. names, just like `%`, `^`, `&`, `"`, `/`, `+`, `(`/`)`, `[`/`]`, `{`/`}`, `,`, `;`, `=`, `'`, `~`, backtick (`) and _space_...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching, I have a solution: Use [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell). It is an advanced command-line tool with scripting language and is available on Windows 7.

Just type power into search on start and click the powershell icon (as illustrated). It might take a second to boot but it is a good utility.

[image]

Here is tabbing (cycling) through alphnumeric folders...

[image: Power 2]

P.s.  Changing the functionailty of the command-line completion on ordinary CMD does not seem to be an option.  You can only turn it on or off.  The other alternative is to download a different SHELL (Console2 for instance) but Powershell works fine and should do all you need.  For the name alone "PowerShell", it is pretty cool ;-)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Solved both problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @viking No probs....good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cd ^
```

followed by the tab key.  You may have to then hit tab a few times to find the desired folder.  Once you do and hit enter, it will change you into that directory.

The ^ key is the escape character for cmd.exe. For example, echo ^ vs echo ^^

Comment: That doesn't seem to change the behavior at all.